# How to make table filter that can search for more than one value in a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a filter that can take multiple values in a table cell. I dont really know how to write an if statement and also how to search for a value. Please help. I also incude a picture of pretty much how I want it to look like.

[image: .]

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("checkbox_check").is(':checked')){
            if($("value"))
        }
    }

    </script>

    <div class="containerFilter">
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox_check">Anglu</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="checkbox_check">Lenku</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="checkbox_check">Italu</div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <section id="table">
        <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gidas</th>
            <th>Kategorija</th>
            <th>Kalbos</th>
            <th>Veda po salis</th>
            <th>Kontaktai</th>
            <th>E-pastas</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Akucevičiūtė, Jūratė</td>
            <td>Aukščiausia - Ekspertas</td>
            <td value="1">Anglų</td>
            <td>Italija</td>
            <td>+370564845698</td>
            <td>rutasiogoliavaitegmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abaravičiūtė, Rūta</td>
            <td>Antra</td>
            <td>Rusų</td>
            <td>Estija, Islandija, Latvija, Lietuva</td>
            <td>+37056965698</td>
            <td>geramoerishotmail.lt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arlauskienė, Vitalija</td>
            <td>Pirma</td>
            <td value="2">Lenkų</td>
            <td>Estija, Latvija, Lenkija, Lietuva, Liuksemburgas, Nyderlandai, Suomija, Švedija</td>
            <td>+37056568698</td>
            <td>gomuriotiesapastininkas.lt</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Akucevičiūtė, Jūratė</td>
            <td>Aukščiausia - Ekspertas</td>
            <td value="3">Italų</td>
            <td>Italija</td>
            <td>+370564845698</td>
            <td>rutasiogoliavaitegmail.com</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i fetched the checkbox value. based on this u can fiilter the table. and i dont know that whether u need the entire row (**tr**)that contains the particular cell that contains the value or that paricular cell (**td**).

```
$('input:checkbox.checkbox_check').click(function () {
       var checked = this.checked;
       console.log(checked);
  });
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Hovewer I decided to do this code a bit differently. For example I put a button and when I press it it searches for all the checked checkboxes. This works but it's really hard and long task to make every checkbox a class and every table row will have more than one class. My question is how can I minimize my efort. Maybe some kind of event or function. I try to use jquery.
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox1").is(':checked'))
     $(".anglu").show();
    else
     $(".anglu").hide();
   });
  });